# Python has unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I used this command for downloading software center

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

this error pops up

```
python-lxml but it is not going to be installed
```

Tried

```
  sudo apt-get purge python
  sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

and now I got more errors

```
software-center :Depends: gvfs-backends
                 Depends: python-lxml but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: update-notifier but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: What possessed you to try purging python? What was the output when you did that?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score -2):

The error here isn't an issue with `python` but with `python-lxml` that it is not installed. Try the following :

> sudo apt-get install python-lxml
>   sudo apt-get install software-center

This shoud resolve your issue.

Comment: If it was that simple Apt would resolve the missing dependency self. -1

Comment: Well that's what I thought but sometimes I have to do it manually so I think it is worth trying.